# Laravel 5.2 - Installing intervation image error command

Tags: laravel, cmd, composer-php

i'm tryng to install intervation image in my laravel project 5.2, i'm tryng install by composer like this:

```
$ php composer.phar require intervention/image
```

but composer give me an error like the image:

[image]

i don't know why, there other way to install it? or fix this issue?

thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

First type composer in you command prompt, check if composer is installed or not. you should see something like that.

[image]

If this is there then composer is installed goto Step 2 , otherwise install the composer from [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

**Step 2**

For intervention image 
go to your root directory of laravel project
run command `composer require intervention/image`

It will download the latest version of composer

after installing go to your config/app.php

in provider array add

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

in alias array add

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

after installing run command `php artisan config:publish`
it will copy the intervention config file to your config directory.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

No need of adding `$` at the beginning.

Just use:

`php composer.phar require intervention/image`

`$` in documentation indicates that the command is to be run in a terminal ( usually Linux ).

Comment: i tryed yes, it return : Could not open input file: composer.phar :(

Comment: @DiegoCespedes You will need to install composer https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your composer.json, then run composer update.

"intervention/image": "2.*"